# DateTime expired check

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to build an extension that will check if a specific date is expired (compared to today's date).

Example: DateTime.Now is: `10/26/2013 11:34:59 AM`

If specific datetime is: `10/22/2013 11:34:59 AM` then return true (expired)

If specific datetime is `10/28/2013 11:34:59 AM` then return false (not expired)

Is this a proper way to do it? (to compare time also because I don't need just the date)

```
public static bool IsExpired(this string specificDate)
{
   bool flag = false;
   DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

   DateTime target;

   if (DateTime.tryParse(specificDate, out target)
   {
     flag = target < currentDate;          
   }

   return flag;     
}
```

Comment: made some changes using try parse ...

Comment: First time I see a question that had any sense edited into a complete nonsense :|

Comment: actually the datetime coming in is string

Comment: sorry my bad ... i get a string not a DateTime so I have to parse that to dateTime

Comment: Why would a date that is less than today's date be expired?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
public static bool IsExpired(this DateTime specificDate)
{
   return specificDate < DateTime.Now;  
}
```